# block in drupal 7 not showing up

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I have created a form within a block, for first time it showed up but it is not showing up again, I have no clue why this is happening as I am quite new to drupal.

```
     <?php

         function my_module_block_info() {
              $blocks = array();
              $blocks['my_block'] = array(
              'info' => t('My Custom Block'),
              );

              return $blocks;
         }
         function hook_block_view($delta = '') {
               switch ($delta) {
               case 'my_block':
               $block['subject'] = t('My form');
               $block['content'] = my_module_my_form();
         }
       }

       function my_module_menu() {
           $items = array();
           $items['my_module/form'] = array(
           'title' => t('My form'),
           'page callback' => 'my_module_form',
           'acess arguments' => array('access content'),
           'description' => t('My form'),
           'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
           'access callback' => TRUE,
            );
       return $items;
           }

        function my_module_form() {
        return drupal_get_form('my_module_my_form');
            }

        function my_module_my_form($form) {

             $form['name'] = array(
             '#type' => 'textfield',
             '#title' => t('username'),
             '#required' => TRUE,
             '#description' => "enter your username.",
             '#size' => 20,
             '#maxlength' => 20,
             );
             $form['picture'] = array(
             '#type' => 'file',
             '#title' => t('Image'),
             '#description' => t('Upload a file, allowed extensions: jpg, jpeg, png, gif'),
              );
     $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => 'update your profile',
     );
     return $form;
 }

    function my_module_my_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
     global $user;
     $account = user_load($user -> uid);
     $image_path = 'picture://';
      $validators = array(
      'file_validate_is_image' => array(),
       );
     $file = new StdClass();
         $file -> uid = $user -> uid;
         $file->uri = $image_path;
         $file = file_save_upload('picture', $validators);
     $new = array (
      'name' => $form_state['values']['name'],
      'picture' => $file,
      );
      user_save($account,$new );
    $message = 'You have updated your profile';
    drupal_set_message(t($message));
 }
```

This form is updating user name and user picture but when I am trying to call this form in a block as its content but its not working after the first time.Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a number of issues with the function

```
function hook_block_view($delta = '') {
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'my_block':
      $block['subject'] = t('My form');
      $block['content'] = my_module_my_form();
    }
}
```

1. You are writing here an implementation of hook_block_view(), not the hook itself, so the function should be called `my_module_block_view()`;
2. The `$block['content']` should be populated with the rendered form, so you need to call `my_module_form()` instead of the form definition function (just like you do in the page callback in the menu hook);
3. Your function doesn't return anything! you should include `return $block;` after the switch statement.

So your function should better be something like

```
function my_module_block_view($delta = '') {
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'my_block':
      $block['subject'] = t('My form');
      $block['content'] = my_module_form();
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}
```